# Twitter streaming API undocumented changes

Tags: twitter, streaming

Has twitter streaming endpoints has changed recently, from https://sitestream.twitter.com/2b/site.json to https://sitestream.twitter.com/1.1/site.json? I could not find any documentation on twitter api documentation page?

Comment: They've been phasing out version 1 of their API recently, which is has impacted the Streaming API. There's not a lot of documentation about these impacts but you can read about some changes at the bottom of this update: https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-retirement-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweeted directly to tweeterapi dev blog writter, he replied, confirming that, api endpoint has been changed from /2b/site.json to /1.1/site.json but /2b/site.json should continue to work. sitestream data fetched should be same.